# JSTL and scriptlets

Tags: jsp, jstl

Can anyone please give the equivalent of the following in JSTL.. 
I am not sure of how to use it

```
<% UserPermissions permission = (UserPermissions) session.getAttribute("permission");%>
..

    <div id="pgcontent">
        <tags:header />
        <div id="maintabs">
            <c:set var="isHome" value="<%=permission.isHome()%>"></c:set>
            <c:set var="isAdministrator" value="<%=permission.isAdministrator()%>"></c:set>
            <c:set var="isOperator" value="<%=permission.isOperator()%>"></c:set>
            <c:set var="isIssuer" value="<%=permission.isIssuer()%>"></c:set>
            <c:set var="isCare" value="<%=permission.isCare()%>"></c:set>

--
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
${sessionScope.permission.home}
${sessionScope.permission.administrator}
...etc
```